# Can't stop a bot without stopping the entire process in pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I've been scratching my head on this for 6 hours now. I am trying to stop my bot, without stopping the entire process. The condition for a bot polling stop is supposed to be that the variable ID is different than the one returned by the get_active_session() function. The bot should start polling again when get_active_sesison() returns a value the same as ID

I've tried so many snippets i lost track of them. In most cases the bot just wouldn't stop even if ID wasn't the same as the one returned by get_active_session()

Heres one of them:

```
def start_polling():
    while get_active_session() != ID:
        try:
            bot.polling(none_stop=True)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Polling error: {e}")
            time.sleep(2)


def stop_polling():
    bot.stop_polling()

print(f"\n\n{get_active_session()}")

while True:
    if get_active_session() == ID:
        stop_polling()
    else:
        start_polling()
```

Comment: Those are all tight infinite loops that will consume all of your CPU.  Surely what you need is a state variable that says "am I running?".  Then, you can decide what state you NEED, and if you are already in that state, you do nothing.  You'll also want to insert some `time.sleep` calls so you don't consume the whole CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I mean.  NOTE that I am assuming that `bot.polling` starts up background activity, and that you don't have to keep calling it in a loop.  If you have to do the main loop yourself, then it would need to be different.

```
polling = False

def start_polling():
    global polling
    if not polling:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    polling = True

def stop_polling():
    global polling
    if polling:
        bot.stop_polling()
    polling = False

print(f"\n\n{get_active_session()}")

while True:
    if get_active_session() == ID:
        stop_polling()
    else:
        start_polling()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Or, use a class to skip the global:

```
class Poller:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.polling = False
        self.bot = bot

    def start_polling(self):
        if not self.polling:
            self.bot.polling(none_stop=True)
        self.polling = True

    def stop_polling(self:):
        if self.polling:
            self.bot.stop_polling()
        self.polling = False

    def mainloop(self):
        while True:
            if get_active_session() == ID:
                self.stop_polling()
            else:
                self.start_polling()
            time.sleep(1)

poll = Poller(bot)
poll.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, that snippet you provided is basically the same thing i've already attempted. (No i don't need to start bot.polling() in a loop). It seems like bot.polling "hangs" the infinite loop. I added a simple print statement at the beginning of the loop print("Looped). The console stops outputting "Looped" as long the bot polling starts.

Sorry if im being kinda stupid, i just started with python

Comment: @sliwka No, you're not being stupid in this case. The fact that ```TeleBot.polling``` blocks thread execution is quite valuable information, that isn't explicitly stated in the pyTelegramBotAPI documentation (it does state that it creates a new thread, but doesn't say anything about thread synchronization.  Although to be fair, there is also an AsyncTeleBot, so, I guess it's implied.) The documentation also states that you should never call ```TeleBot.polling``` more than once however, implying you should probably recreate the bot entirely before starting polling again.